# Serde::Serialize/Deserialize for BoundedVec

Tags: pallet, genesis

Do I have to manually Serialize/Deserialize BoundedVec?

Update:
There was no implementation, so I'm coding one [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11314)

Comment: No, you don't need to manually do it. What's your use case?

Comment: I want to use BoundedVec at GenesisConfig

Comment: Are you getting any errors on that?

Comment: Here the details: at GenesisConfig [memories: Vec<(T::AccountId, Vec<(ID, Vec<ID>, Value)>)>](https://github.com/DigitaIAM/nae-substrate-node/blob/main/pallets/nae/src/lib.rs#L84) and Value is [here](https://github.com/DigitaIAM/nae-substrate-node/blob/main/pallets/nae/src/lib.rs#L55). After adding `String(BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxString>),` to enum compiler raise error **the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `BoundedVec<u8, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxString>`**

Comment: I believe this should resolve by adding support to serde::Serialize.

Comment: where it should be added? I do have [it](https://github.com/DigitaIAM/nae-substrate-node/blob/main/pallets/nae/src/lib.rs#L51)

Comment: in your derive attribute.

Comment: Well, as mention above I do have it. And code compile until I add `String(BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxString>),`

Comment: Can you please add it like this?
#[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen, CloneNoBound, RuntimeDebugNoBound, PartialEqNoBound, EqNoBound, Serialize, Deserialze)]

Comment: As expected, same error. I don't see any Serialize/Deserialize implementation for BoundedVec or I'm missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure about this then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved with a PR from @shabanovd

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11314

Should not be an issue anymore.